# Minimal multithreaded transaction with Hibernate

Tags: multithreading, hibernate, jta, embedded-jetty

I'm using Hibernate in an embedded Jetty server, and I want to be able to parallelize my data processing with some multithreading and still have it all be in the same transaction. As Sessions are not thread safe this means I need a way to get multiple sessions attached to the same transaction, which means I need to switch away from the "thread" session context I've been using.

By my understanding of the documentation, this means I need to switch to JTA session context, but I'm having trouble getting that to work. My research so far seems to indicate that it requires something external to Hibernate in the server to provide transaction management, and that Jetty does not have such a thing built in, so I would have to pull in some additional library to do it. The top candidates I keep running across for that generally seem to be large packages that do all sorts of other stuff too, which seems wasteful, confusing, and distracting when I'm just looking for the one specific feature.

So, what is the minimal least disruptive setup and configuration change that will allow getCurrentSession() to return Sessions attached to the same transaction in different threads?

While I'm at it, I know that fetching objects in one thread and altering them in another is not safe, but what about reading their properties in another thread, for example calling toString() or a side effect free getter?

Comment: `Session` is **not** thread safe. You **cannot** access the same session in multiple threads. You need a `Session` per thread. To share a database transaction across these threads, you need to look into JTA. JTA is incredibly complex, and requires special database connections (XA compatible), a special connection pool, and a number of other things. In short, what you are asking to do is **nowhere near** as simple as you think it is.

Comment: Right, I misspoke on the "same session" thing. What I need is multiple Sessions in different threads associated with the same transaction. Edited to correct that. All I need is the ability to declare the start of a transaction, declare the end of a transaction, and have those declarations be respected across threads. That seems a sufficiently basic and commonly needed concept that I'd be surprised if there's really nothing that abstracts away the details.

Comment: There is, it's called JTA. But as I said, its very difficult to provide ACID guarantees across threads. You would need to use something like Atomikos with an XA compatible database and XA connections. Synchronizing transactions across multiple database connections is a task that is far more complex than you seem the think.

Comment: Is the processing to be parallelized hibernate db access heavy? Otherwise you could perhaps parallelize all except hibernate db access and have the parallel running threads communicate with single threaded db hibernate access.

Comment: @Douglas as to your second question, no; you cannot do that either. There is **no** guarantee, without `final` or `volatile`, that you will read an updated value. Because threads have their own local caches on modern CPUs, the JVM provides no guarantees what value of an unsynchronized field a thread will see. You can even get access to an `Object` before its constructor has been fully run, due to instruction reordering. This is the [Visibility problem](https://www.bionicspirit.com/blog/2013/03/14/jvm-multithreading-monitor-locks-visibility.html).